# Using the wp_remote_post response body

Tags: php, http, http-api

I don't have great PHP skills, but can usually fumble my way through with a little bit of direction, so I'm hoping someone on here can help me.

I am doing a http post submission from a form to a third party API and am having trouble using the response value.

They are returning a URL with a query string value that I need to capture in order to determine the correct confirmation method to display.

I am using `wp_remote_post()` as follows:

```
$response = wp_remote_post($post_url, array('method' => 'POST', 'body' => $body));
```

The submission works but I get the returned URL as an HTML stream in `$response['body']` but I cannot seem to get any query string values from it.

So my question is: Is there a way I can capture the actual URL value with query string that they send, rather than this being interpreted as an HTML stream?

To test their response, I created a very simple HTML form and when submitted, the URL of the page that the HTML form is on, does change from `example.com/form` to `example.com/form?status=1`.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

> The submission works but I get the returned URL as an HTML stream in
>   `$response['body']` but I cannot seem to get any query string values
>   from it.

That is what is supposed to happen. You requesting a *web page* just as when you click a link in a web browser, except programatically.

Again...

> Is there a way I can capture the actual URL value with query string
>   that they send, rather than this being interpreted as an HTML stream?

... doesn't make a lot of sense. You are requesting a web page. "They" are not sending an "URL value with query string". You are sending one and a server is responding. As you are requesting a web page, what you get is a web page. However the body of the page is not the only thing returned. [Check the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post#Return_Values):

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [date] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 15:16:36 GMT
            [server] => Apache
            [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.3.3
            [x-server] => 10.90.6.243
            [expires] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 03:16:36 GMT
            [cache-control] => Array
                (
                    [0] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
                    [1] => post-check=0, pre-check=0
                )

            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [content-length] => 1641
            [connection] => close
            [content-type] => application/php
        )
    [body] => <html>This is a website!</html>
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Perhaps what you are looking for is in the headers.

Comment: I am dumping both my request and their response to a log file. They are apparently responding with a url value that contains a query string. When I capture this and write it to the log, the 'body' of their response contains the html of the webpage they are responding with. I would like to capture the url of the 'webpage' they are sending back. It is not in the header of their response.

Comment: The URL of the webpage is the same URL that you request. I don't know why you insist that the site responds with an URL value. That is very weird behavior for a web server. It is like saying the page you request turns around and requests a page from you.